# open() doesn't set O_CLOEXEC flag

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls, fcntl

I try to set O_CLOEXEC flag using open() and have no sucess.

Consider the following microtest:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
  int fd = open("test.c", O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
  int ret = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
  if(ret & O_CLOEXEC) {
    printf("OK!\n");
  } else {
    printf("FAIL!\n");
  }
  printf("fd = %d\n", fd);
  printf("ret = %x, O_CLOEXEC = %x\n", ret, O_CLOEXEC);
  return 0;
}
```

When running on linux with kernel version 2.6 the test succeeds and prints "OK!", but fails with 3.8 or 3.9 kernels.

What's wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: notice that the flag can be true even before O_CLOEXEC support in 2.6.38

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was decided that exposing `O_CLOEXEC` flag to `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` is security leak. Change was made by [this commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c6f3d81115989e274c42a852222b80d2e14ced6f) in kernel 3.6-rc7:

```
commit c6f3d81115989e274c42a852222b80d2e14ced6f
Author: Al Viro <viro@zeniv.linux.org.uk>
Date:   Sun Aug 26 11:01:04 2012 -0400

don't leak O_CLOEXEC into ->f_flags

Signed-off-by: Al Viro <viro@zeniv.linux.org.uk>
```

In other words, you should not have relied on `O_CLOEXEC` being visible in first place.

Answer (score 2):

The fcntl call parameter `F_GETFD`, the flag is `FD_CLOEXEC` and the `O_CLOEXEC` support appeared in 2.6.`23`. Read the manuals:

```
 File descriptor flags
   The following commands manipulate the flags associated with a file descriptor.
   Currently,  only one such flag is defined: FD_CLOEXEC, the close-on-exec flag.
   If the FD_CLOEXEC bit is 0, the file descriptor will  remain  open  across  an
   execve(2), otherwise it will be closed.

   F_GETFD (void)
          Read the file descriptor flags; arg is ignored.

   F_SETFD (int)
          Set the file descriptor flags to the value specified by arg.
```

Comment: OP said he succeeds in kernel 2.6 but fails on 3.8/3.9

Comment: The test fails when running on kernel 3.8 that obviously supports O_CLOEXEC. Please read the question.

Comment: This answer is correct inasmuch as the *right* way to get the `CLOEXEC` status is to use `F_GETFD` and test for `FD_CLOEXEC`, because `CLOEXEC` is a flag that applies to each file descriptor, rather than the underlying open file.  That doesn't explain why the ABI for `F_GETFL` apparently changed, though.

Comment: Could you please cite the spec describing the _right_ way? From manuals I see that the test is perfectly _right_.

Comment: No, it is never documented like that. `F_GETFL` is just the open flags of the file; someone decided that the bit should be taken out as it does not affect the opened file but the file descriptor only. That is why it is not documented.

Comment: Furthermore, F_GETFL seems to return whatever was given to the open, less filtered flags, even ignored ones.

Comment: Thus it was never a reliable way to see if a flag was supported.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong. You should do by this way:

```
int ret = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);
if (ret & FD_CLOEXEC) {
...
}
```